# Using a Vue.js filter in a conditional statement

Tags: vue.js

I am using the [vue-currency-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-currency-filter)

and it works great. But there are times when the value it filters is not a number in my application. When that occurs it just show $0. I want it to show the text value that is not a number.
when I have 345.23 I get $345.23
when I have 'No limit' I get $0 and i really want 'No Limit'

I have tried to include a ternary in my view but it fails. And i think that is related to [this](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5449).
Which i get but how can i solve this with a method?

Here is my relevant view html:

```
<div>{{ ch.Limit | currency }}</div>
```

and i tried something like:

```
<div>{{ Number.isNaN(ch.Limit) ? ch.Limit : ch.Limit | currency }}</div>
```

which doesn't work.
I also tried to create a method like this:

```
valueIsCurrency(k) {
  return Number.isNaN(k) ? k | currency : k;
},
```

coupled with:

```
<div>{{ valueIsCurrency(ch.Limit) }}</div>
```

but the currency filter is not respected in the method. I suppose it is only for use in the render html portion.
How can i fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

template

```
<div v-if="isNumber(ch.Limit)">{{ ch.Limit | currency }}</div>
<div v-else>{{ ch.Limit }}</div>
```

code

```
methods: {
  isNumber(n) {
    return typeof n === 'number';
  }
}
```

Comment: @DerekPollard he's corrected the answer. Please don't hold people hostage with your votes.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu the problem is it creates yet another reason for people to consider SO a hostile place. Threatening with votes is not productive or polite.

Comment: @DerekPollard then write the answer that IS correct and let it get upvoted. That's the whole point of multiple answers and voting. This isn't a forum. Please, be civil and simply mention mistakes and work them out with conversation, not threats.